# How do I select a row from nearly duplicate rows based on a field value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I have rows with this data:

```
ID |Name        |ContractType|
---|------------|------------|
 1 |Aaron Shatz | 6-month    |
 2 |Jim Smith   |12-month    |
 3 |Jim Smith   | 6-month    |
 4 |Mark Johnson|12-month    |
```

I can't use Id to determine which record to use: I have to use *ContractType*. I want to select all records from a table, but if there are records with the same *Name* value, I want to pick the *12-month* contract record.

The result of the query should be:

```
ID |Name        |ContractType|
---|------------|------------|
 1 |Aaron Shatz | 6-month    |
 2 |Jim Smith   |12-month    |
 4 |Mark Johnson|12-month    |
```

Comment: Are the only contract types 6- or 12-month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works *only* because the OP has confirmed that only two contract types are possible, and the one he wants (for each contractor) happens to be the one that orders first alphabetically. So a couple of coincidences make this solution straight-forward.

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ID, Name, ContractType, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ContractType)
  FROM dbo.some_table
)
SELECT ID, Name, ContractType 
  FROM x
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY ID;
```

If you need to make this more dynamic, I suppose you could say:

```
DECLARE @PreferredContractType VARCHAR(32);
SET @PreferredContractType = '12-month';

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ID, Name, ContractType, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CASE ContractType
      WHEN @PreferredContractType THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    )
  FROM dbo.some_table
)
SELECT ID, Name, ContractType 
  FROM x
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: So this won't work if contracts in the future are added then. Currently, there are two, but would you mind commenting on a dynamic version, say if I had to specify which contract I wanted to be the one in a stored proc? If not, no big deal. You answered the question I asked.

Comment: @Yatrix - With more than 2 contracts it's not as simple as "I want the 12 month contract".  What if you introduce a 9 month contract and there are records with a 6 month contract and a 9 month contract, but not a 12 month contract?  The rule needs to change to somethign like "the longest contract".

Comment: The update I made will return the 12-month contract if it exists. If a 12-month contract doesn't exist, it will pick an arbitrary one. You could extend this to have a `@SecondChoiceContractType` if needed.

Comment: Hey, worked like a charm with some tweaking. A lot of cool stuff in SQL I have no clue about, but this is one more I know now. Just wanted to say thanks again. =)

Answer (score 5):

## Hard coded version

This solution assumes that there are only two contract types namely 6-month and 12-month. Please scroll to the bottom for **`dynamic`** version.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59d08/1)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE contracts
(
        id              INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,   name            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   contracttype    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO contracts (name, contracttype) VALUES
    ('Aaron Shatz',     '6-month'),
    ('Jim Smith',       '12-month'),
    ('Jim Smith',       '12-month'),
    ('Mark Johnson',    '12-month'),
    ('John Doe',        '6-month'),
    ('Mark Johnson',    '6-month'),
    ('Aaron Shatz',     '6-month');

SELECT id   
    ,   name
    ,   contracttype
FROM
(
    SELECT  id  
        ,   name
        ,   contracttype
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY contracttype) AS rownum
    FROM    contracts
) T1 
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

*Output*:

```
id  name          contracttype
--  ------------  ------------
1   Aaron Shatz   6-month
2   Jim Smith     12-month
4   Mark Johnson  12-month
5   John Doe      6-month
```

## Dynamic version

This moves the *contract type* data into a table of its own with a *sequence* column. Based on how the contract types are ordered, the query will fetch the appropriate records.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c16a/1)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE contracts
(
        id              INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,   name            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   contracttypeid  INT         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE contracttypes 
(
        id              INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,   contracttype    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   sequence        INT         NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO contracttypes (contracttype, sequence) VALUES
    ('12-month', 1),
    ('6-month',  3),
    ('15-month',  2);

INSERT INTO contracts (name, contracttypeid) VALUES
    ('Aaron Shatz',     2),
    ('Jim Smith',       2),
    ('Jim Smith',       3),
    ('Mark Johnson',    1),
    ('John Doe',        2),
    ('Mark Johnson',    2),
    ('Aaron Shatz',     2);

SELECT  id  
    ,   name
    ,   contracttype
FROM
(
    SELECT  c.id    
        ,   c.name
        ,   ct.contracttype
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ct.sequence) AS rownum
    FROM            contracts           c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contracttypes       ct
    ON              c.contracttypeid    = ct.id
) T1 
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

*Output*:

```
id  name          contracttype
--  ------------  ------------
1   Aaron Shatz   6-month
3   Jim Smith     15-month
4   Mark Johnson  12-month
5   John Doe      6-month
```